# .vimrc settings not saved between bash sessions on Windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, vim

If I edit my `.vimrc` file adding new settings, and then exit my bash session and open a new one, all the settings are gone. The `.vimrc` file always reverts back to having these contents:

```
syntax on
set shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 expandtab
```

I edit the `.vimrc` file by first entering bash, and the going to my home directory using `cd ~`. When I'm there I type `vi .vimrc`. To save my new settings I do `:w!` and then `:q!` to exit.

Whenever reentering bash, the new settings are overwritten with the block I pasted above.

*EDIT*

Here are the contents of my `.profile`:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: Do `ls -l .vimrc` to see if the timestamp indicates that the file was overwritten after you edited it, may be upon logging in.  I have a suspicion that your .profile (or .bash_profile etc) might be initializing the .vimrc file and that why it is getting overwritten when you re-login.

Comment: Yes, it is being overwritten on login, as proven by checking the timestamp like you suggested. I'm not sure where the overwriting is happening though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem as pointed out by codeforester. There was a line in my `.bashrc` that was overwriting my `.vimrc` on startup.